# Unable to switch os in dual booting

Tags: linux, windows, boot, secure-boot

I got a new laptop ((Asus vivobook 14)https://www.flipkart.com/asus-vivobook-14-ryzen-5-hexa-core-4500u-8-gb-512-gb-ssd-windows-10-home-m413ia-ek582t-thin-light-laptop/p/itm8d1c44556be49?pid=COMFSKF9ZWGMFX4D&lid=LSTCOMFSKF9ZWGMFX4DEMHVKL). It came pre-installed with Windows 10 and I dual booted Pop_OS 20.04. For that, I disabled secure boot. The installation was successful but when I tried to switch to windows it asked me for the recovery key. After a little googling I realized the problem can be fixed by turning on enter the secure boot.

But, with secure boot enabled, when I try to open Linux, I get the following message on my screen.

[image: Message]

I even tried entering the recovery key, thinking that might help but it kept prompting the message every time I logged into windows with secure boot disabled

Is there a way to keep a general setting and easily navigate between the two operating systems?

Comment: This question is off-topic here. You may be able to get help with your personal computer at our sister site [su].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Recovery keys are used with Bitlocker. Disable Bitlocker on the Windows partition.

Comment: Thank you @unNamed , Now i can easily use my both OS. I disabled the encryption in the Security setting in the windows. And now it works fine